# Patching strategy and versioning for JBoss 6.4

Tags: jboss, redhat, patch

We are using JBoss EAP 6.4 as part of a third-party software package we run on our servers. In the installation notes, it states that we have to install in as follows:

1. Install JBoss 6.4.0
2. Install JBoss 6.4 Patch 9 (6.4.9)
3. Install JBoss 6.4 Patch 12 (6.4.12)

There is a specific note that JBoss patching is incremental and therefore we have to patch both 6.4.9 and 6.4.12. In scripts provided by the manufacturer I also found references to those specific two patch versions.

I'm confused. I would have expected either to have an cumultative patch (e.g. install 6.4.0, install patch 12), or incremental patches (install 6.4.0, then patch 1, then patch 2, etc).

I googled and did not managed to find a good explanation for these requirements.

What's the logic behind JBoss (6.4) patching and what's so special about patch 9 to warrant the special inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update instructions (as found on the download page) for JBoss EAP 6.4 patch 10 say that you have to apply the update to patch 9 first.  This carries forward to future patch updates.  There is a [knowledgebase article which should mention this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2605021) (it currently doesn't say that this applies to patch update 10 *and later*, but this should be fixed).

Comment: So 1-9 in included in Update 9, and 10-12 are included in Update 12?

Comment: Yes, based on the download pages, this should be the case. If still in doubt, please contact Red Hat support.

Comment: to be precise  to install, for ex, patch 6.4.2x (ex: 6.4.21), you would need to install first 6.4.9, then 6.4.19 then the 6.4.2x patch you need  (ie,  patch 6.4.21 only contains patches 20 and 21, and patch 6.4.19 only contains patches 6.4.10 to 6.4.19. This is done to limit patch size. see note  https://access.redhat.com/articles/2605021)